# C++ User input string error

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting a strange error when I am trying to get user input as a string.

I have the correct includes;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
```

This is the code, where when executed I get the error;

```
write("Enter your name");
string name = readString();
write(name);
```

The above code calls these two functions;

```
void game::write(std::string message)
{
    cout << message << "\n";
}

string game::readString()
{
    string userInput = NULL;
    std::cin >> userInput;
    return userInput;
}
```

This is the error I get:
[image: C++ Error]

I have tried re-building the solution - should I used a char array rather than string as the data container for text in my application??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not initialize a string from a `NULL` pointer. Try:

```
string userInput = "";
```

or simply

```
string userInput;
```

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) and check ctor no. 5, based on the C++ standard:

> #### 21.4.2 basic_string constructors and assignment operators [string.cons]
>
> `basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());`
>
> <sup>8</sup>          *Requires:* s shall not be a null pointer.

Comment: That worked completely - I am such a N00b!! I feel a fool to have asked this on StackOverflow - now I see how simple the answer was.

Comment: @ConnorJackson: Happens to everyone in the beginning. IIRC, there were even STLs that in the past would have accepted your code.

Comment: @Danel Frey - I have 2 other read functions, readInt and readChar - on both of those they accept NULL - but looking at it string is different as its also like a class type rather than a data type. - if that makes sense.

Comment: @ConnorJackson: Generally, I try to avoid `NULL` as much as possible. Use `0` for numeric types, `'\0'` for character types, default construction for `std::string`, etc. and [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) (when available) for pointers.